# ShellCheck warning: "Iterating over ls output is fragile. Use globs. [SC2045]"

Tags: bash, ls, shellcheck

I am getting a ShellCheck warning [SC2045] for the second line in the code below. Is it fine to ignore it as I am making sure the directory is not empty before I try the last `ls`?

```
 if [ "$(ls -A "$retryDir")" ]  ; then
    for thisRetryFile in $(ls "$retryDir"/*.tar.gz) ; do
        scp -o ConnectTimeout=30  "$thisRetryFile"  \             
              "$remoteUser@$remoteHost:$remotePath" >> "$BACKUPLOG"
    done
 fi
```

**UPDATE:**
After reading the post comments. I have changed the line to:

```
for thisRetryFile in "$retryDir"/*.tar.gz ; do
```

This has removed the warnings.

Comment: See [BashPitfall #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: Empty directories aren't the only problem. Filenames with spaces are also a problem.

Comment: [why not parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: OK I see. Thanks .

Comment: Oh and filenames containing wildcard characters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the loop with a glob, and also set `nullglob` to avoid executing `scp` in case the pattern doesn't match anything.
And you don't need the outer `if` condition either,
since the `for` with `nullglob` effectively takes care of that:

```
shopt -s nullglob

for thisRetryFile in "$retryDir"/*.tar.gz; do
    scp -o ConnectTimeout=30  "$thisRetryFile" \
          "$remoteUser@$remoteHost:$remotePath" >> "$BACKUPLOG"
done
```

If you want to catch the case when no file matches the pattern,
you can write like this, without using `shopt -s nullglob`:

```
for thisRetryFile in "$retryDir"/*.tar.gz; do
    if [ -f "$thisRetryFile" ]; then
        scp -o ConnectTimeout=30  "$thisRetryFile" \
            "$remoteUser@$remoteHost:$remotePath" >> "$BACKUPLOG"
        break
    else
        echo "warn: no tar.gz file in dir: $retryDir"
    fi
done
```

Comment: That's really a matter of opinion. The really safe alternative is to *handle* the case of no matches in every location where you use a wildcard. Then whether you use nullglob or something else will be case by case; some things are harder when your argument might disappear.

Comment: @AndyM yes, like that

Answer (score -2):

This is safer. Try it.

```
 if [ "$(ls -A "$retryDir")" ]  ; then
    for thisRetryFile in ${retryDir}'/*.tar.gz' ; do
        scp -o ConnectTimeout=30  "$thisRetryFile"  "$remoteUser@$remoteHost:$remotePath" >> "$BACKUPLOG"
    done
 fi
```

Regards!

Comment: No, this still violates [don't use `ls` in scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).